# Saving numerical values to a *.dat file

Tags: export

I have a function like this:

```
F[m_, t_] = Sum[Sum[Q[[m,i]]*Q[[m,l]]*SS[t], {l, 2, Y}], {i, 2, Y}]
```

How can I save values of this function to some `.dat` file so I can read the values when required?

Comment: Did you look at `Export`? `Save`? `DumpSave`?

Comment: yes i have tried those.. to save my large matrices i use Put i.e. >> command and use =<< to read it when i need it. but this comand is not working in case of a function F[m,t]

Comment: Tangentially related: "[The best way to construct a function with memory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5287817/590388)."

Comment: Your question has the same problem as [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89541/plot-experimental-data-from-dat-file): `DAT` is a file *extension*, not a file *format*. One of the most common file formats with `DAT` extension used to be raw MPEG2 stream. I presume you don't want that. If you have specific requirements of the file format, you should specify it more directly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using [Save](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Save.html):

```
Clear[f];
f[x_] := x^2;
Save["testf.m", f];
Clear[f]
Get["testf.m"];
?f
```